# How can I append the images from this JSON file properly into the correct divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am making an Instagram web page clone and I have everything built out. I can retrieve the data from the JSON file and add it to the `<img>` tag, but I need each image to display above its own version of the `.below-image` div. I know that I need to somehow append the `.below-image` section to each image that is placed into the `#images` div, and I have done that, but for whatever reason, I can't seem to figure out how to separate every image so that there is congruent spacing between each item.

I have also created a https://jsbin.com/zagejacowe/edit?output

**HTML**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Instagram Feed</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="feedstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='feed.js'></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="top">
        <!-- <div id="home-button">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SmdPZ6T.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="profile-photo">
          <img src="https://scontent-sea1-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-19/10731946_1517235648523785_1216221661_a.jpg" />
        </div> -->
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></li>
          <li id="logo">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SmdPZ6T.png" />
          </li>
          <li id="profile-photo">
            <img src="https://scontent-sea1-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-19/10731946_1517235648523785_1216221661_a.jpg" />
            <p class="username">username</p>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </header>


    <div id="container">
      <main>
        <div id="feed-container">
          <div id="feed-posts">
            <div id="images">
              <!-- <ul>
                <li>
                  <img src="http://yourbizrules.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Staying-Motivated.jpg" />
                </li>
                <div class="below-image">
                  <div class="like">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="image-info">
                    <p>User Info</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="more">
                    <button>···</button>
                  </div>
                  <div id="clear"></div>
              </ul>
              <div id="add-a-comment">
                <div class="comment-container">
                  <form class="comment" action="index.html" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Add a comment...">
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  font-family: "proxima-nova", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #3E6D93;
  height: 50px;
}
.top {
  background: #467ea6;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0.01, #467ea6), to(#27608c));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#467ea6', endColorstr='#27608c', GradientType=0);
  width: 100%;
}
.top li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#home-button, .fa-home {
  float: left;
  background-color: #305F87;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 35px;
}
.fa-home {
  padding-left: 12px;
}
#logo img {
  float: right;
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  padding: 6px;
}
#profile-photo  {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #305F87;
  border-right: 1px solid #305F87;
  width: auto;
}
#profile-photo img  {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#profile-photo p {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;

}
#feed-container {
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
  width: 650px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#feed-posts {}
#images {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#images img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
}
.below-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.like {
  float: left;
}
.fa-heart {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.image-info {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 437px;
  height: 52px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.image-info p {
  color: #467ea6;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.more {
  float: right;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
.more, button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
#clear {
  clear: both;
}
.comment-container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 200px;

}

#add-a-comment {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 550px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#add-a-comment p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#add-a-comment input[type=text] {
  width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
}
input, select, textarea{
  color: #f00;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
 var bottom =    '<div class="below-image">' +
                '<div class="like">' +
                  '<i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="image-info">' +
                  '<p>User Info</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="more">' +
                  '<button>···</button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="clear"></div>' +
              '</ul>' +
                '<div id="add-a-comment">' +
                  '<div class="comment-container">' +
                    '<form class="comment" action="index.html" method="post">' +
                      '<input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Add a comment...">' +
                    '</form>' +
                  '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>';



$(document).ready(function() {
  var jsonURL = "https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json";
  $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json) {
    var imgList = "";
    //var newImage = "http://yourbizrules.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Staying-Motivated.jpg";

    $.each(json, function() {
      imgList += '<li><img class="inserted" src= " ' + this + ' "></li>' + bottom; 
    });
    $('#images').append(imgList);
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this appends that section to the bottom of the page properly, but I need to have this `.below-image` section append to every `<img>` tag. :(

Comment: You know that an `id` should be unique? Right now you're adding a div element with an id equal to `images` for every image.

Comment: Sorry, that is not my intent. I am not very good with JQuery. I simply want to append all of the images into the div with the `id #images` and then have each image attach the `.below-image` section of the html to said image. What would be the best way to go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you change the foreach loop to this one:

```
$.each(json, function(i) {
  imgList += '<ul><li><img class="inserted" src= " ' + json[i] + ' "></li>' + bottom; 
});
```

Here as jsfiddle (+update): http://jsfiddle.net/bg3x0k7n/1/

Comment: Thank you! It works, but exactly as I have it currently. Were you able to separate all of the images and divs with your solution?

Comment: can u explain what you mean with seperate?

Comment: oh, I see an error in your html. you should put a <ul> at the beginning of each image, I edited my answer

Comment: Sure. currently all of the images as well as each or the `below-image` sections are smashed together and overlapping. I can't for the life of me figure out how to push them apart. I'm sure it is something small, but I can't locate the issue.

Comment: Ahh! I just saw your update. THANK YOU! I knew it was something minuscule. You are wonderful!

Comment: your welcome. But let me tell you something. You use a list <ul> and inside first a <li> and then a <div> - you should only put <li> as childs of <ul>. I would wrap the whole image and its bottom, with the comment in an <li> and all the images in an big <ul>. That would be a more semantic solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91140/discussion-between-jshuadvd-and-jacksbox).